# Combine rows in DF keeping the one of the repeated values

Tags: r, dataframe

**Hi everyone! Im trying to clean a merge between a lot of databases.**

**Currently I have this:**

```
  Nombre     Mail       Status.GG   Status.MC   number   Cargo  Empresa   Origen    
  Nicolas    n.rojas@   Si          Si          NA       pr     NA        NA    
  Nicolas    n.rojas@   Si          NA          569      pr     RRHH      Evento    
  Nicolas    n.rojas@   NA          NA          569      pr     RRHH      Evento    
  Nicolas    n.rojas@   NA          NA          NA       pr     NA        NA    
  Pedro P    pp@        NA          No          123      teach  UAI       NA    
  Pedro P    pp@        NA          NA          123      NA     UAI       NA    
  Pedro P    pp@        SI          NA          123      teach  UAI       NA    
  Pedro P    pp@        SI          NA          123      teach  NA        NA
  Andres L   anl@       NO          No          456      NA     UV        NA
  Andres L   anl@       NO          NA          NA       Dir    NA        NA    
  Andres L   anl@       NO          No          456      NA     UV        NA
```

**Intended solution:**

```
**Nombre     Mail       Status.GG   Status.MC   number   Cargo  Empresa   Origen**  
 Nicolas    n.rojas@   Si          Si          569      pr     RRHH      Evento    
 Pedro P    pp@        SI          No          123      teach  UAI       NA    
 Andres L   anl@       NO          No          456      Dir    UV        NA
```

**Closer solution found**

```
DTB <- setDT(basetest)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) paste(x[x!=''], collapse='')) , Nombre, .SDcols= Mail:Origen]
```

**the only problem is that this solution creates the following:**

```
  Nombre     Mail             Status.GG  Status.MC  number        Cargo       Empresa     Origen    
  Nicolas    nr@nr@nr@        SiSiNANA   SiNANANA   569569NANA    prprprpr    RRHH...     Evento    
  Pedro P    pp@pp@pp@pp@     NANASISI   NoNANANA   123123123123  teach....   UAI...      NA    
  Andres L   anl@anl@anl@anl  NONONO     NoNANANo   456NA456      Dir....     UV...       NA
```

**Thanks!**

**PD: I don't mind if the solution is data.table, tidyverse, or else.**

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse` you can try to fill the NAs with previous or next values. And then filter for unique rows.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Nombre) %>%
  fill(names(.),.direction = "downup") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  unique()
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8
  Nombre  Mail     Status.GG Status.MC number Cargo Empresa Origen
  <fct>   <fct>    <fct>     <fct>      <int> <fct> <fct>   <fct> 
1 Nicolas n.rojas@ Si        Si           569 pr    RRHH    Evento
2 PedroP  pp@      SI        No           123 teach UAI     NA    
3 AndresL anl@     NO        No           456 Dir   UV      NA
```

Comment: it didn't work, i believe it's because that some of my columns have more than two consecutive blanks. Thanks though! Any more ideas?